# Importing an asc PADs file into Eagle

Tags: eaglecad, footprint

I have a [.asc PADS file](http://www.linear.com/designtools/packaging/foot/DFN10DDB3X2.asc) that defines the footprint for a part I am using. Is there any way I can use this file with Eagle so that I don't have to make the package from scratch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any Eagle user scripts for importing files from PADS. I suspect that your best bet is to design your own footprint using Eagle for the part.

If money is no object, I found a company who claim to do conversions: http://www.logicswap.com/eagle.php

Answer (score 1):

PADS .asc file describes PADS board layout, not only component footprint. To transfer PADS footprint to another program (like EAGLE) so called .d file has to be exported from PADS (PADS Library Manager). There is a utility called Eagle2Pads (http://www.cadware.cz/index.php?lang=en&page=128) for data conversion between EAGLE and PADS, both schematic and board layout, with components library bidirectional conversion tool to follow soon.

Answer (score -2):

I imported the file into the Pulsonix software I use without any problems. It's a very simple footprint and it shouldn't take you more than five minutes to create it yourself.